# Is it possible to sync Eclipse plugins between multiple computers?

Tags: eclipse, synchronization

I've been trying to set up automatic synchronization of plugins for Eclipse, but I haven't had any luck so far. Is there any way to automatically synchronize Eclipse plugins (such as EGit) between multiple Eclipse installations across different operating systems (such as Mac, Windows, and Linux?)

Comment: It would be great if I could find a way to synchronize plugins between multiple Eclipse installations (the same way that Chrome extensions can be synced with multiple Chrome installations). Is this feasible, or are there cross-platform compatibility issues that would complicate this process?

Comment: Installing Eclipse plugins manually on multiple computers can be tedious, so I'm looking for a way to automate the process.

Comment: Install the Eclipse plug-ins on one machine, zip Eclipse, and unzip your customized Eclipse on the other machines.  You'll have to create a zip for each operating system / hardware combination that you have.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Is there any way to automate the synchronization process?

Comment: Sure.  One way is through the FTP process.  Google "unzipping remote files" and pick a method that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Sync plugin is supposed to do that I think. It can use Dropbox or a local folder to sync plugins.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-sync

Hasn't been updated for a year though.